# How can I delay the closing tag in a Jade template?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I am having an issue with Jade and Bootstrap. I am trying to layout some HTML in this format:

```
<bootstrap row>
   <bootstrap col-sm-6>
   <bootstrap col-sm-6>
</bootstrap row>
<bootstrap row>
   <bootstrap col-sm-6>
   <bootstrap col-sm-6>
</bootstrap row>
```

etc...

I need this to happen inside an each statement however I cannot get it to work quite how I'd like it. It keeps closing the row after each iteration so I get:

```
<bootstrap row>
   <bootstrap col-sm-6>
</bootstrap row>
<bootstrap row>
   <bootstrap col-sm-6>
</bootstrap row>
```

This is the Jade template I currently have:

```
div.col-sm-12
  #items
    - each item, x in items
      div.article.col-sm-6
        div.title
          h3= item.name + " (" + item.cost + ")"
          p= item.stats
          p= item.recipe
          p= item.ability
          p= "Purchased from " + item.category
```

So, for each 2 iterations, I need to wrap the two col-sm-6 items in a row.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to only render `item` when the index is even, and within that condition render the next item. Something like:

```
.col-sm-12                   
  #items                     
    - var items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 
    - each item, index in items
      if 0 === index % 2  
        .row                 
          - var nextItem = items[index + 1] 
          .col-sm-6= item                                                                                                                                  
          .col-sm-6= nextItem
```

The output:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div id="items">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">a</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">b</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">c</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">d</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, since your `item` and `nextItem` isn't as simple as this example you may need to use a partial to render each with the appropriate markup for its values.